# MariaDB/MySQL Physical Storage

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I need to centralize my database storage on a NAS attached to a router. It does not look like I may run a MariaDB from there (the router may not provide the resources needed to handle the database with at most 50k records). Still I should be able to create the physical storage on that NAS while having the software in another machine, that way a number of other machines may connect to the database tables views and progs stored on that NAS. This way I would not need to leave any machine on to handle SQL requests apart from the router that is always on.

In clear software interacting with the tables should be on my computers and the tables on my NAS (like, for instance, I would do with sqlite that, though, would not manage concurrent writing).

In light of all that, how may I install MySQL so that database physical storage is in that NAS and launch my query and commits from several other computers?

P.S. for more background, this is a centralized kodi install on different machines. My understanding is that kodi would access the MySQL database on my NAS but then the DB installed there would not have the resources for the daemons to work. I tried installing MariaDB/MySQL but found no option for separating physical tables from software handling them.

Comment: I might be wrong but it looks like kodi clients can be used as substitutes for mysql clients, but you will need a central mysql server to handle the requests. Are you saying you want to put the Mysql servers on the client machines and just point them to the files on the NAS? Do you want to be able to use more than one client at once, because I think that would be a problem in such a configuration. Also, I would expect table files stored on a NAS would give poor database performance, but it may be good enough depending on what you need.

Comment: Buffalo made some NAS years ago that had Win Server on them so you could do this but the NAS has to be intelligent, you are asking a Hub to be a Switch sort of thing.

Comment: Thank you both. Simon you got .y question and yes kodi should act as a client for any request. In principle I would not use simultaneously my clients though this should be applicable to mysql.. anyways I am willing to try if I found a way to install on my disk the data part only.

Comment: I think the assumption that your router (or NAS) cannot handle MariaDB running 50k records maybe incorrect. Its really tiny and especially if the tables are index correctly very little resources are needed I think it would be a good solution compared other machines. Sometimes even NAS solutions have a MariaDB database option.